# asp.net core won't bind the id value

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the standard default route mapped.

```
app.UseMvc(config =>
        {
            config.MapRoute(
                "Default", 
                "{controller=App}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
        });
```

In one of my controllers I have an action:

```
 public IActionResult EditTask(int taskId)
```

I used the FIrefox dev toolbar to verify that the ID value is passed correctly:

```
  window.location = "/Admin/EditTask/" + dataItem.TaskId;
```

I don't get why asp.net will not map the taskId to the action parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `EditTask(int taskId)` to `EditTask(int id)`